# onOptionsItemSelected not called when pressed back button on Action bar - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

When I press the back button of my action bar, the method onOptionsItemSelected of my fragment it never called. I want to go to the previous fragment when I pressed the button but this method it never calls. This is the code for the Fragment, what it could be the problem?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Get item selected and deal with it
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //called when the up affordance/carat in actionbar is pressed
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

First of all this will be received in base activity not fragment.
Add your previous fragment to back stack.
And from this fragment popup

> if(id==android.R.id.home)
>           {
>               getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
>           }

And to check from which fragment it has been called use:
if (fragment instanceof MyFragment)
You're done!!

Comment: This method is never called in base activity. In the previous fragment I do the following: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment(), "fragment").addToBackStack("fragment").commit(); I don't understand why onOptionsItemSelected is never called when I pressed the back button of the action bar

Comment: Whenever you press back button of Action bar; onOptionsItemSelected() of Activity will be called always(since action bar belongs to activity not fragment). So put debugger on corresponding activity of fragment; I am sure the method will be called. I have the implemented and running code.

Comment: In the previous fragment I do mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); and I think that it is could be the reason why when I press the back button in the action bar nothing occur. But if I don't do that, then when I press the back button appear the navigation drawer and I don't want to do that, I want to go to the previous fragment and not permit acces to the navigation drawer. What can I do? Thanks!!

Comment: Pamela,ask a separate question for that.If your current problem is solved please mark this as answer